# Merge rows with common field value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, duplication

I have a table which was imported from MS-SQL, it has about 1.9 million rows. After importing I realized that a lot of the rows are duplicates and there are no primary key constraints.

The rules to check for constraints are:

- Check the email address.
- If no duplicate is found in the table, leave the row as it is.
- If email address matches then compare the columns in both.
- Select one of the two as the row that will be kept i.e. TO_KEEP, the other will be deleted i.e. TO_DELETE.
- If there is any column in TO_DELETE that has some value but there is no value in TO_KEEP the update the TO_KEEP row with the value from the matching column in TO_DELETE.

I need help with writing a query for that. It's beyond my current skills. I wouldn't mind if I get some pointers which can make it easier as to how the query can be structured and which ones to use.

Comment: You can probably use the tips mentioned here [remove duplicate rows in mysql table that does not contain primary key](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/21314)

Comment: That one is slightly different as that table has only one column so the query is much simpler. But, thank you for the pointer, I found a more relevant thread http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/php-mysql-merge-duplicate-records-in-table-and-create-a-new-table